# Check for nulls in linq statement so an error doesnt occur

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

What is the best way for me to check for null values so I don't get an error when this statement executes:

```
if (Levels.Count(x => x.Location.ToUpper() == code.ToUpper()) == 1)
```

I need to make sure Location is not null because it keeps throwing an object reference exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Where` operator

```
if (Levels.Where(x => x.Location != null)
          .Count(x => x.Location.ToUpper() == code.ToUpper()) == 1)
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you mameesh

Answer (score 2):

try this

`if (Levels.Count(x => x.Location!= null && x.Location.ToUpper() == code.ToUpper()) == 1)`